# How do you make an editable label in iOS (like naming a Reminders list)?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel

You know how in Reminders the name of the list doesn't look like a text field, it looks like a label (which makes it bloody confusing in my opinion, but never mind that), but you can edit it?

I'd like to do the same thing in my app - either have a label you can edit, or a text field that looks like a label.  Is there a function for doing that, or would you need to do something where touching the label makes a text field appear, which disappears later (and updates the label text)?

Don't worry, by the way, it won't be as confusing in my app as it is in Reminders.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a text field and make it look like a label. Primarily, change the `borderStyle` of the view, but you can also make changes to the `layer` properties.

Comment: That's the ticket!  Getting rid of the border and changing the text size is pretty much spot on :)  Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved as follows:-

```
UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:fieldFrame];
[field setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[field setText:@"Editable field..."];
[field setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:field];
```